# Laravel 5, Eloquent relationship/ Method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphism

I have 3 tables in laravel 5.6

**First Table**

```
//Table1> users: id | name
//and in Model: User
public function bookmarks()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Bookmark::class);
}
```

---

**Second Table**

```
//Table 3> bookmarks: user_id  | bookmarkable_id  | bookmarkable_type     
// and in Model: Bookmark
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Product', 'bookmarkable');
}
```

---

**Third Table**

```
//Table3> products: id | title | user_id
//and in Model: Product
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function bookmarks()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Bookmark', 'bookmarkable');
}
```

Now, I want return all bookmarked products for current user:

```
$products = auth()->user()->bookmarks()->products()->latest()->paginate(18);
```

But I get this error:

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::products does not exist."

What is my wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best to way to this is reverse your thinking a little bit. Go from the Product model (as you want a collection of products) and work your way back through the bookmarks with a `whereHas` which filters down by the current users ID.

```
$bookmarkedProducts = Product::whereHas('bookmarks', function($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', auth()->id());
});
```